# FCM push notifications are sending but not delivering for iOS 13

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, firebase, push-notification

I'm using Firebase and have integrated FCM into my project. I have everything hooked up correctly notification wise because I can send and receive notifications on my device when I send notifications from the Firebase console Notification Composer. However when I try to send a notification from my device it sends but the device doesn't receive it. Here's my AppDelegate code:

```
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    return true
}

       func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
  // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
  // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.

}


     func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
   {
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        print("Token has been recieved.")
   }

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {



    }
```

And here is my index.js code:

```
     const functions = require('firebase-functions');
     const admin = require('firebase-admin');
     admin.initializeApp();

     var db = admin.database();
     var usersRef = db.ref('/Users')

    // Values for sending notifications
    var currentUsername = String()
    var notificationMessage = String()

    exports.sendInviteNotification = 
    functions.database.ref('/Users/{userID}/signals/inviteSignal/toUID').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
     let userID = snapshot.val()

     var currentUserRef = usersRef.child(context.params.userID)
     currentUserRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {

    currentUsername = snapshot.child('username').val();
    notificationMessage = snapshot.child('/signals/inviteSignal/message').val();

    console.log('notification sent from:', currentUsername, 'notification sent to:', userID, 'message body:', notificationMessage)

})

  var toUserRef = usersRef.child(userID)
  toUserRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {

    let fcmToken = snapshot.child('fcmToken').val();
    console.log(fcmToken)

    var payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "Invite from ${currentUsername}",
                body: notificationMessage,
                }
        }



    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, payload)
        .then((response) => {
        console.log('Successfully sent notification:', response)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error)
        })

})


return true
```

})

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No this is what is displayed in my firebase console log "Successfully sent notification: { results: [ { messageId: '1589707119833271' } ],
  canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
  failureCount: 0,
  successCount: 1,
  multicastId: 5994394047919796000 }"

Comment: Can you put some logs in the node js side ? Does the json body for push notification is constructed properly?  In my case , I created a new p12 certificate and updated it in the firebase console which resolved the issue.